# How to make a global address book for all customers in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I'm investigating if there is a possibility to pre-populate the address book with some fixed shipping addresses for all customer in my Magento 1.6.1 Community shop? So the address select box in the onstepcheckout gets populated for all customers?

Of course it is possible but I don't know where to start? Any links to resources or perhaps extensions that does this would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks,
Ismail

Comment: I've never heard about something like a "global" address book in Magento; I guess an easy way would be to statically store a pre-filled SELECT in the appropriate template.

Comment: That could be one solution. Although I want to leverage the functionality of the admin panel for this. So if I add a new shipping address to a customer it will be visible for all.

Comment: Think about that idea twice. If an address is added to a customer, it should be the customers personal address and only be visible for this single customer and the shop owner. Otherwise any of your customers would have access to some pretty private data from the other customers. You definitely need a separate storage for global addresses.

Comment: In my case, the shop is made for a company and the use it internally to send marketing material to their different sub-units. So there are no privacy issues I need to think about. I only want to have some fixed shipping addresses so that the employees don't have to look up addresses everytime they make an order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys!

I made a custom extension for Magento. If you want it you can comment below.

Best,
Ismail

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be done by creating a module.  Whether something like this already exists, I don't know, but I doubt it.

All you'd really have to do is override the shipping template, or possibly the block that's generating the select html.

I haven't looked into how it's done exactly.  If you need more help, I'd be happy to assist, but these are general guidelines of what you'd have to do.  I'm assuming you already know how to create a module.